# Cannot debug Xamarin android app because NDK registry is missing

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.android, android-ndk, ms-android-emulator

Anytime I run the debugger and emulator it just errors with this message.
Multi-device C++ development is enabled.

I'm not sure what to do.

```
Unable to start debugging.
A required Visual Studio registry value could not be found.
Ensure that support for multi-device C++ development is enabled in Visual Studio setup.

Registry key: Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_e34a64fc\Setup\VS\SecondaryInstaller\AndroidNDK
Value name: NDK_HOME
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is some problem with the NDK in your visual studio.

1. You can try to add a enviroment variable named `NDK_HOME` if there is a NDK in the Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_e34a64fc\Setup\VS\SecondaryInstaller\AndroidNDK
2. You can try to reinstall or update the visual studio, actually the the NDK will be installed into the path by the visual studio installer when you install the visual studio.

You can check the following case:[XA5104 Could not locate the Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69455429/xa5104-could-not-locate-the-android-ndk) and [Where is android-ndk located?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52306639/where-is-android-ndk-located)